# Docker windows save to filesystem

Tags: docker, filesystems

I'm having a docker application that writes to the local filesystem on a windows machine.

When I run/debug the application from Visual Studio it works, but when I then run the image in docker I get "Could not find part of the path". And that is usually an indication of insufficient rights to write in that folder.

But now I'm confused, is it not in both circumstances using my credentials?

Anyway in an attempt I have tried to give everyone full control, but still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, it turns out to be that when I do the docker run command I have to use the `-v` parameter

Like this:

```
docker run --rm -it -v c:\hostcontainershare:c:\containertmp myconsoleapplication  ".NET Framework App Writing to Host Folder" 1
```

I found the explanation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814415.aspx

And when you run it from Visual Studio, it apparently does that automatically for you.